# Regex version number with negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I've been using the following regex to parse out version numbers from artifactory `\d+\.\S*\d`

For my use case it was working great at either picking up the version number or a version number with a string.

ie

```
amazon-agent-helpdesk-1.0.10.tgz > 1.0.10
gk2-utils-1.0.0-1065298.tgz > 1.0.0-1065298
```

Now we have new versions that have been uploaded and are essentially duplicates that I don't want to include. These new versions will always have `-amd64` plus some additional characters after that. I wanted to be able to stop the match if there is `-amd64` or `-linux`.

ie

```
1.0.10 > 1.0.10
1.0.10-amd64-21736 > 1.0.10
1.0.10-amd64-21736-linux-amd64 > 1.0.10
1.0.10-linux-21736 > 1.0.10
1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033 > 1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033
1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033-amd64-11240 > 1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033
```

I've tried some different variations of adding a negative look ahead like:
`\d+\.\S*\d(?!-amd)` but I can't seem to get the regex correct.

How could I edit the regex to find the version number plus any string except if the string after the version number starts with `-amd` or `-linux`?

List I'd like to still match:

```
amazon-agent-helpdesk-1.0.10.tgz > 1.0.10
gk2-utils-1.0.0-1065298.tgz > 1.0.0-1065298
1.0.10 > 1.0.10
1.0.10-amd64-21736 > 1.0.10
1.0.10-linux-21736 > 1.0.10
1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033 > 1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033
1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033-amd64-11240 > 1.0.20-SNAPSHOT-1359033
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might write the pattern asserting the specific alternatives to the right

```
\b\d+\.\S*?\d+(?=-(?:amd64|linux)\b|$|\.tgz)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+\.` Match 1+ digits and `.`
- `\S*?` Match optional non whitespace chars, as few as possible
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `-` Match a hyphen
  - `(?:amd64|linux)\b` Match one of the alternatives, followed by a word boundary
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\.tgz` Match the specific extension
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5LvZme/1).

Or as an alternative, you can match the leading numbers with a dot in between, followed by matching non whitespace character except for `-` or `.`

But only match `-` if it is not directly followed by `-amd` or `-linux`

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)+[^-\s.]*(?:-(?!(?:amd64|linux)\b)[^-\s.]*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8ZNLL/1)

Comment: Brilliant. Why the need for the positive look ahead mixed with non capture group?
What does the \b do after the non capture group?

Comment: @VirtualPenman the `\b` after the 2 "words" prevent a partial word match. The non capture group is the group the 2 alternatives so that the `-` is before both words.

Comment: Ah I see. When using the ^ and $ to designate the start and end of the string, does that indicate the start and end of the match string or literal string? I'd like to still be able to match against `gk2-utils-1.0.0-1065298.tgz` string and get `1.0.0-1065298`. Would I be able to adjust the ^ $ in order to still match the version in that string?

Comment: @VirtualPenman That depends on the different strings. The `^` and `$` assert the start and end of the string. The the other case, a pattern like this would match it https://regex101.com/r/5LvZme/1

Comment: Or another option could be like this https://regex101.com/r/hvMSuu/1

Answer (score 3):

You may also try this regex without any lookahead:

```bash
^\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?:-SNAPSHOT-\d+)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xvmsJm/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)+`: Match dot followed by 1+ digits. Repeat this group 1+ times
- `(?:-SNAPSHOT-\d+)?`: Match an optional text starting `-SNAPSHOT-` followed by 1+ digits.